# Cómo puedo filtrar por fechas?

Tags: python, django

quiero crear una especie de archivo por fechas, en el cuál por ejemplo pueda seleccionar el mes de marzo y se muestren las publicaciones creadas en esa fecha, alguien podría orientarme un poco?
Este sería mi archivo de models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    titulo = models.CharField('Título del post', max_length = 100, null = False, blank = False)
    categoria = models.CharField(max_length = 255, default='elegir categoria')
    contenido = RichTextField()
    miniatura = models.ImageField('Portada')
    slug = models.SlugField('Slug', max_length = 100, blank = False, null = False)
    fecha_publicacion = models.DateTimeField('Fecha de publicación', default = timezone.now) 
    ultima_actualizacion = models.DateTimeField('Última actualización', auto_now = True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Post'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Posts'

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.titulo or ''

    def __str__(self):
        return self.contenido or ''

    def __str__(self):
        return self.author or ''

    def __str__(self):
        return self.categoria or ''
```

Answer (score 1):

En `modelos.py` defines y ordenas de la forma conveniente los datos que quieres guardar en la base de datos, datos persistentes.

Pides mostrar un filtro por fechas. Esto va fuera de `models.py` ya que forma parte de como muestro esos datos guardados. Hay que separar.

La forma mas rapida y facil es utilizar el `frontend` de `djangoadmin` añadiendole el paquete [`django-admin-rangefilter`](https://github.com/silentsokolov/django-admin-rangefilter).

1. Instala el paquete `pip install django-admin-rangefilter`.
2. Añada la aplicaacion en INSTALLED_APPS de settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'rangefilter',
    ...
)
```

3. Juega con el siguiente código base. Se basa en el campo `fecha_publicacion`

admin.py

```
import datetime

from django.contrib import admin
from rangefilter.filter import DateRangeFilter, DateTimeRangeFilter

from .models import Post


@admin.register(Post)
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = (
        ('fecha_publicacion', DateRangeFilter), 
    )

    # If you would like to add a default range filter
    # method pattern "get_rangefilter_{field_name}_default"
    def get_rangefilter_created_at_default(self, request):
        return (datetime.date.today, datetime.date.today)

    # If you would like to change a title range filter
    # method pattern "get_rangefilter_{field_name}_title"
    def get_rangefilter_created_at_title(self, request, field_path):
        return 'custom title'
```

#### otros

Tienes repetido el metodo `__str__()` . Solo se va a ejecutar el primero.  Deja uno, el que quieras.

```
    def __str__(self):
        return self.contenido or ''

    def __str__(self):
        return self.author or ''

    def __str__(self):
        return self.categoria or ''
```